# Object Reference lost on multy layer async await operation

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, garbage-collection, async-await

I have come across some behaviour that has left me baffled a little as to the behaviour of async await pattern with the garbage collector. here is an interpretation of the production code.

```
public async Task CreateProduct(int id)
{
    Product result = factory.Create(id);
    await AssignPrices(result);
    GC.KeepAlive(result);
    Assert.That(result.Prices.Count == 1); //this is true   
}

public async Task AssignPrices(Product value)
{
    foreach (var engine in pricingEngines)
    {
        await engine.AddPrice(value);
    }
}

public class DefaultPricingEngine
{
    public async Task AddPrice(Product value)
    {
        var price = await _externalApi.GetPrice();
        value.Prices.Add(price);
    }
}

class Product
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public List<decimal> Prices {get;set;}
}
```

if i omit the `GC.KeepAlive` it seems to revert to the initially created product. where as if i keep it in, the prices are added as expected.

What exactly is happening here that is causing the clean up.. and is the `GC.KeepAlive` a false positive of that is really going on.

Comment: This very much needs a MVCE. Encapsulate this in a small Console or WinForms app. The cause could very well be in the surrounding project.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with references or garbage collection.

You call `AssignPrices` which is an async method without awaiting it. This means you have a race condition on your hands.

The async method will run synchronously on the calling thread until the first await is reached and the method returns control with a task representing the rest of the operation. If you don't await it (or block on it synchronously) the calling method will run in parallel with the unawaited async operation.

Using `GC.KeepAlive` only works by delaying the calling method while `AssignPrices` gets a chance to complete.

You should await the operation and only move on when it's complete. You should also add the "Async" suffix to async methods which helps in reminding you to await it.

```
public async Task CreateProductAsync(int id)
{
    Product result = factory.Create(id);
    await AssignPricesAsync(result);
    Assert.That(result.Prices.Count == 1);
}
```

Comment: sorry i forget the await in the pseudo code. i can verify that in the production code all are awaited. (this is just some psuedo code i threw together to post online)

Comment: @BastanteCaro well, this code looks fine then. If you have code that reproduces the issue then you should post it.

Comment: as for GC.KeepAlive, i was under the impression it is not blocking but informs the GC thread to not mark the specified object for collection.

Comment: @BastanteCaro I didn't it's blocking. Though it is, in the sense that it uses the thread to perform the operation and only "frees" it when it's done.

Comment: this is as close to the production code as it gets tbh. what was baffling was it looks fine to me and other developers here. debugging it and assigning objectId's shows that after the await AssignPrices is called the reference seems to change.

Comment: @BastanteCaro - _just some psuedo code i threw together_ is a huge waste of our time. Write a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @henk the above is mvce, just with sensitive code parts removed. Your comment is unhelpful and unnecessary..

Comment: @BastanteCaro no, it's not verifiable.

Comment: Ok. No stress, if no one knows the reason for the behavior I noticed. I'll close it. I was looking fur some insight on what might have being causing the behavior not a working result as I already have that. Thanks for your efforts